# Fix Safari offsetTop with scrollable divs

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a scrollable div with a collection of elements inside. When I use `element.offsetTop` I get different lengths in Safari and Chrome/Firefox.

I'm using angular 2 AfterContentInit Hook.

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.ticketsService.getData().subscribe(() => {
      this.zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(() => {
        let scrollPosition = calculateElementHeight(this.tickets.toArray()[1].nativeElement);
        console.log(scrollPosition);
        this.scrollable.setScrollPosition(scrollPosition);
      });
    });
  }
```

Safari log: 137 x2, 137, 92 x2, 92 x2

Chrome/Firefox log: 92 x2, 92 x2, 92

How can I fix it?

PD: jQuery solutions are not valid.

PD2: I can use AfterViewChecked because when user use the scroll, this one should works so this event should stop. That's the problem, I don't know how this event should stop.

Answer (score 0):

If done in AngularJS try listening to [$viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) as such:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event, args) {

    // do what you want to do
});
```

Or:

```
$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function()
        {
            alert("blah");
        });
```

Or Angular 2:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ticketsService.getData().subscribe(() => {
      this.zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(() => {
        let scrollPosition = calculateElementHeight(this.tickets.toArray()[1].nativeElement);
        console.log(scrollPosition);
        this.scrollable.setScrollPosition(scrollPosition);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: That's not the problem, I'm executing this over Angular 2 AfterContentChecked event, I'm absolutely sure that properties are set.

Comment: Well instead of voting the answer down you could tell in your question that this is done in AngularJS ;)

Comment: Nop,I'm using Angular 2 and this works ngAfterContentChecked. xD

Comment: Not 100% sure about angular 2 but try instead of AfterContentChecked() try ngAfterViewInit()